# How set FontName to TextRange in Framemaker?

Tags: framemaker

This is my code , set font of `TextRange`

`iFont=119`, `font name ="Tunga"`

```
var oTypedValRp = new TypedVal();
oTypedValRp.valType = Constants.FT_Integer;
oTypedValRp.iVal = iFont;                                                  
oDoc.SetTextVal (oTextRange,Constants.FP_FontFamily, oTypedValRp);
```

But Result :`TextRange` has font name =`"Symbol"`

Why? How can set font to `TextRange`?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i set font ok by code:

```
var props = AllocatePropVals(1);  
props[0].propIdent.num = Constants.FP_FontFamily;  
props[0].propVal.valType = Constants.FT_Integer;  
props[0].propVal.ival = iFont;     

oDoc.SetTextProps(textRange, props);
```